# Using VBA to execute a formula and then jump to next row

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance! I am not a programmer in any way, shape, or form...but I am looking for help to get a spreadsheet I use daily to work more efficiently, and I think I need to use VBA to do it.

Basically what I am doing is using a barcode scanner to scan a pile of files and then search a list of files due to see if they are on it.  I have conditional formatting set up that flags the files on my list if they are scanned.  The format of the list I am searching only has the last 5 digits of the file number, however the actual file barcode contains 10 numbers.  I have a simple two column sheet set up where I scan the barcode, it automatically tabs to the right (the function of the scanner) where I was using the =Right(j9,5) formula to pull the last 5 digits out.  That works beautifully, but what I would like to do is have it then automatically jump down to the next row (1,-1) after the formula is entered.  Basically, I just want to be able to scan a whole stack of files without pressing ENTER between each one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can configure the scan to send an CRLF after each scan. Or print a bar code of enter key, CHR(13) or VBCRLF and scan this after every scan

Comment: How is the formula being entered?

Comment: @horaciux the separate barcode is genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I used a lot. As this solve your problem too, I post it as an answer.

You can configure the scan to send a CRLF after each scan. Or print a bar code of Enter key, CHR(13) or VBCRLF, and scan this after every scan.